# $request->getParameter with array - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

If I have:

```
$_POST['test']
```

then can I use:

```
$request->getParameter('test');
```

But how can I use this if I have `$_POST['test']['two']`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now only one way do to it:

```
$arr = $request->getParameter('test');
$two = $arr['two'];
```

Edited:

In PHP 5.4 you can do it `$request->getParameter('test')['two'];`

Answer (score 9):

Symfony version 6.0, the correct answer is

```php
$request->request->all('test')['two'];
```

When you ask for array in GET call:

```php
$request->query->all('test')['two'];
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Symfony 2, there's even a prettier solution to get array values with the Symfony Request:

```
$request->get("test[two]", null, true)
```

The third parameter of `get()`, `$deep`, is false by default and decides whether you can access array keys.

See the documentation of the ParameterBag:

> boolean   $deep: If true, a path like foo[bar] will find deeper items

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html#method_get

As [antongorodezkiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741782/antongorodezkiy) pointed out in his comment to this answer, please note that this "is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0."

Comment: Please note that "Finding deep items in `ParameterBag::get()` is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0." https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/CHANGELOG-2.8.md

Answer (score 2):

```
$request->getParameter('test')['two'];
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a easy way to get the whole request

```
$var = $request->request->all()
```

$var will be an array.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#accessing-request-data